# Angular 2 - How to pass pipe from ts file

Tags: angular

**app.component.ts**

```
    export class AppComponent {

    private productdata = [{
        "ProductName": "Chang",
        "UnitPrice": 18.0000,
    },
    {
        "ProductName": "Chai",
        "UnitPrice": 22.0000,
    }
    ]; 
   }
```

**app.component.html**

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Product Name</th>
        <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let data of productdata">
        <td>
            {{data.ProductName}}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{data.UnitPrice | currency:'USD':true:'1.2-2'}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The above code works fine.Now, I have tried to pass currency pipe from ts file like :

in ts file

```
public format: any = currency:'USD':true:'1.2-2';
```

in html file

```
<td>
        {{data.UnitPrice | format}}
</td>
```

but its not working.Is this a right way to apply currency filter like this?Can anyone help?

Comment: What's the purpose of it? It you want to change parameters dynamically in component, you can inject CurrencyPipe in your component and use transform method with necessary parameters to format value there

Comment: CurrencyPipe is not fixed. It can be any pipe.

Answer (score 1):

Pipe is actually not a string value. So you can do this instead:

```
public format: string = 'USD';
```

in HTML

```
<td>
     {{data.UnitPrice | currency:format}}
</td>
```

To make it more dynamic

```
public pipe: any = {
    name: 'currency',
    format: 'USD'
}
```

in HTML

```
<div *ngIf="pipe.name=='currency'">
    <div>{{value|currency:pipe.format}}</div>
</div>
<div *ngIf="pipe.name=='date'">
    <div>{{value|date:pipe.format}}</div>
</div>
```

OR using switch

```
<div [ngSwitch]="pipe.name">
    <div *ngSwitchCase="'currency'">
        <div>{{value|currency:pipe.format}}</div>
    </div>
    <div *ngSwitchCase="'date'">
        <div>{{value|date:pipe.format}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: {{data.UnitPrice | currency:format}} is working but {{data.UnitPrice | format}} is not working

Comment: Yes the second one will not work because pipe is not a string value, the value you pass to the pipe is a string 'USD'. So you can make that string value dynamic. So, use this to pass currency value from typescript {{data.UnitPrice | currency:format}}

Comment: Actually CurrencyPipe is not fixed. It can be any pipe.

Comment: your answer is absolutely correct, but doesn't fulfill the requirement